# How can I debounce a setOnClickListener for 1 second using Kotlin Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, debouncing, kotlin-flow

When user taps fast on the button the showDialog() method displays multiple times on top of each other, so when you dismiss it there is another one behind it. I am looking for a way to ignore the second tap for 1 second without using a handler or check the previous tap's time.

```
//Button that opens a dialog
button.setOnClickListener {
    showDialog()
}
```

I am looking for a solution using Kotlin coroutines or Kotlin flows for future implementations.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's better to use a simple **Flag** for that instead of delay as it's not a good user experience.

But if you want to use Coroutines, You can simply use [Kotlin Coroutine's Flow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/) to apply this:

First I created an **Extension Function** for the click event that returns a Coroutine's Flow. like this:

```
    fun View.clicks(): Flow<Unit> = callbackFlow {
    setOnClickListener {
        offer(Unit)
    }
    awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
   }
```

Now, All you need is Calling your Function in **onCreate** like this:

```
button.clicks().debounce(1000).onEach { println("clicked") }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
```

Don't forget to add these lines in build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.3'
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.3'
```

**Edit:**

The Flow analogue of **throttleFirst** operator is not implemented yet in kotlin coroutines. however, can be implemented with the help of Extension Functions:

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> Flow<T>.throttleFirst(windowDuration: Long): Flow<T> = flow {
    var lastEmissionTime = 0L
    collect { upstream ->
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val mayEmit = currentTime - lastEmissionTime > windowDuration
        if (mayEmit)
        {
            lastEmissionTime = currentTime
            emit(upstream)
        }
    }
}
```

The changes are as follows:

```
binding.button.clicks().throttleFirst(1250)
        .onEach {
            //delay(100)
            showDialog()
        }.launchIn(GlobalScope)
```

Also, you can use a delay() to handle this. Take it easy to change value of these parameters according to your needs.

Comment: My understanding is that this produces the same result as the solution of @qki. The result indeed prevents the creation of multiple dialogs, however if the user keeps clicking on the button repeatedly, the dialog will not appear until the 1 sec passes.

Comment: internal debounce() method is not useful in your case. you should customize it. I also edited my answer to using throttleFirst Flow operator.

Comment: Yes, the use of throttleFirst() provides the expected result. I am not sure about the use of delay() in the body it seems that it is delaying the display of the dialog but also not preventing the creation of new dialogs. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe launchIn(mainScope) is better.

Answer (score 20):

Couroutines are overkill for something as trivial as debounce:

```
class DebounceOnClickListener(
    private val interval: Long,
    private val listenerBlock: (View) -> Unit
): View.OnClickListener {
    private var lastClickTime = 0L

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        val time = System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (time - lastClickTime >= interval) {
            lastClickTime = time
            listenerBlock(v)
        }
    }
}

fun View.setOnClickListener(debounceInterval: Long, listenerBlock: (View) -> Unit) =
    setOnClickListener(DebounceOnClickListener(debounceInterval, listenerBlock))
```

Usage:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(1000L) { doSomething() }
```

Comment: I should clarify, this isn't exactly the same as debounce. There's no delay for the first click, which I think is better for responsiveness. It's more analogous to `throttleFirst`.

Answer (score 2):

I honestly recommend [corbind](https://github.com/LDRAlighieri/Corbind)

With this great library you can forget about `setOnClickListener` and just handle flows like

`binding.myButton.clicks()
                .debounce(500)
                .onEach { doSomethingImportant() }
                .launchIn(viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope)`

It's really easy to use, and with view binding making an app becomes super simple. I hope it helps, happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, looks like a cool library however I can't use a whole new library for now. Also, if I repeatedly click on the button the dialog will never appear until I stop for whatever the timeout is set on the debounce method. Maybe I would need something else like a throttleFirst() method?

Answer (score 1):

###### To improve [Morteza Nedaei's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60234167/421467):

If you try that code within a timeframe of 2000ms and a window duration of 500ms, it will be triggered only 4 times; while it should be 5 times.

Morteza's:

> 237: #1-(0-500)
> 839: #2-(501-1000)
> 1440: #3-(1001-1500)
> **????: #?**
> 2041: #5-(2001-2500)

Improved one:

> 236: #1-(0-500)
> 637: #2-(501-1000)
> 1038: #3-(1001-1500)
> 1639: #4-(1501-2000)
> 2039: #5-(2001-2500)

---

```kotlin
fun <T> Flow<T>.throttleFirst(windowDuration: Long): Flow<T> = flow {
    var windowStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var isEmitted = false
    
    collect { value ->
        val currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val delta = currentTime - windowStartTime
        
        if (delta >= windowDuration) {
            windowStartTime += delta / windowDuration * windowDuration
            isEmitted = false
        }
        if (isEmitted.not()) {
            emit(value)
            isEmitted = true
        }
    }
}
```