# Debounce user input in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, debouncing

Suppose I receive user input which triggers a method call (or any other event triggers this method call), which needs to make a backed call or save something in DB, but the user input is very fast and I am not interested in all inputs, e.g. I need a debounce operation over this fast input. I was able to solve the problem using conflated channel and below is a small demo showing my solution:

```
class Coroutines {

    val chanel = Channel<String>(Channel.CONFLATED)
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    fun run() {
        val input = Scanner(System.`in`)

        scope.launch {
            listen()
        }

        var inputStr = ""
        while (inputStr != "q") {
            inputStr = input.nextLine()
            println("Input is $inputStr")

            scope.launch {
                chanel.send(inputStr)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private suspend fun listen() {
        while (true) {
            val msg = chanel.receive()
            println("Received $msg")
            delay(3000)
        }
    }
}
```

I feel there must be a better solution to this problem, maybe something using Coroutines Flow? Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I debounce a setOnClickListener for 1 second using Kotlin Coroutines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60190103/how-can-i-debounce-a-setonclicklistener-for-1-second-using-kotlin-coroutines) --I suggest looking at my answer as the accepted answer uses a coroutines, which are like taking a sledgehamer to a nail.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to debounce the user click input then do something like this.

```
   const val CLICK_DEBOUNCE = 300L

/**
 * click flow
 */
fun View.asClick(): Flow<Unit> = callbackFlow {
    this@asClick.setOnClickListener {
        this.offer(Unit)
    }
    awaitClose { this@asClick.setOnClickListener(null) }
}
```

then call like this.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        binding.btnSaveFile.asClick().debounce(CLICK_DEBOUNCE).collect {
            //do something
        }
    }
```