# Android EditText Coroutine debounce operator like RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I need to make EditText with autosuggest functionality and I need to listen to its input. I also need to ignore EditText change when it is set programmatically.

Wondering if there is solution to make debounce EditText with Coroutines without using delay in this situation.

Comment: I answered a similar question for buttons here, and my comment would be the same. Coroutines are unnecessary complexity for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60193549/506796

Comment: You are probably right, but this is my way of learning Coroutines, so I had to try it.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### Turn text change event to a `Flow`

> Use kotlinx.coroutines 1.5.0

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@CheckResult
fun EditText.textChanges(): Flow<CharSequence?> {
  return callbackFlow<CharSequence?> {
    val listener = object : TextWatcher {
      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit
      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        trySend(s)
      }
    }
    addTextChangedListener(listener)
    awaitClose { removeTextChangedListener(listener) }
  }.onStart { emit(text) }
}
```

If using `androidx.core.widget.doOnTextChanged`:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@CheckResult
fun EditText.textChanges(): Flow<CharSequence?> {
  return callbackFlow {
    checkMainThread()

    val listener = doOnTextChanged { text, _, _, _ -> trySend(text) }
    awaitClose { removeTextChangedListener(listener) }
  }.onStart { emit(text) }
}
```

### Use:

```kotlin
editText.textChanges().debounce(300)
    .onEach { ... }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

And something like this:

```kotlin
fun executeSearch(term: String): Flow<SearchResult> { ... }

editText.textChanges()
    .filterNot { it.isNullOrBlank() } 
    .debounce(300)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .flatMapLatest { executeSearch(it) }
    .onEach { updateUI(it) }
    .launchIn(lifecycleScope)
```

Source code: https://github.com/Kotlin-Android-Open-Source/MVI-Coroutines-Flow/blob/master/core-ui/src/main/java/com/hoc/flowmvi/core_ui/FlowBinding.kt#L116

Comment: And what is trySend() function ?

Comment: @Vetalll Since Coroutines 1.5.0 https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/try-send.html

Comment: it works like a charm

Comment: for some reason, distinctUntilChanged, filters out the typed character

Comment: @hardik9850 that depends on your case :))

Comment: How do I use this from inside onBindViewHolder in my recyclerview? There is no `lifecycleScope` :(

Comment: No type arguments expected for class Flow is CharSequence

Comment: Updated : fun EditText.textChanges() = callbackFlow {
            val listener = object : TextWatcher {
                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit
                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    trySend(s)
                }
            }
            addTextChangedListener(listener)
            awaitClose { removeTextChangedListener(listener) }
        }.onStart { emit(text) }

Answer (score 5):

After doing some research on Coroutines and Flow I came up with solution on creating custom EditText which holds debounce logic inside it and enables me to attach debounce TextWatcher and remove it when I want. Here is the code of my solution

```
class DebounceEditText @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attributeSet: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : AppCompatEditText(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr) {

    private val debouncePeriod = 600L
    private var searchJob: Job? = null

    @FlowPreview
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun setOnDebounceTextWatcher(lifecycle: Lifecycle, onDebounceAction: (String) -> Unit) {
        searchJob?.cancel()
        searchJob = onDebounceTextChanged()
            .debounce(debouncePeriod)
            .onEach { onDebounceAction(it) }
            .launchIn(lifecycle.coroutineScope)
    }

    fun removeOnDebounceTextWatcher() {
        searchJob?.cancel()
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private fun onDebounceTextChanged(): Flow<String> = channelFlow {
        val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                offer(p0.toString())
            }
        }

        addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

        awaitClose {
            removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to activate Debounce TextWatcher, I just call

```
// lifecycle is passed from Activity/Fragment lifecycle, because we want to relate Coroutine lifecycle with the one DebounceEditText belongs   
debounceEditText.setOnDebounceTextWatcher(lifecycle) { input ->
    Log.d("DebounceEditText", input)
}
```

I had problem with focus when implementing DebounceEditText inside xml, so I had to set clickable, selectable and focusableInTouchMode to true.

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
```

In case I want to set input in DebounceEditText without triggering, just remove TextWatcher by calling

```
debounceEditText.removeOnDebounceTextWatcher()
```