# skip delay in kotlin coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is there any way to skip a delay in kotlin coroutines.

```kotlin
setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
    override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {

        // todo: skip the delay

        return true
    }

    private var textChangeCountDown: Job? = null
    override fun onQueryTextChange(text: String): Boolean {
        textChangeCountDown?.cancel()
        textChangeCountDown = lifecycleScope.launch {

            // here is the dalay that need to be skipped when query text submit
            delay(800)

            // text changed to $text

        }
        return true
    }
})
```

When the user click submit, I want to skip the delay, just something like like:

```kotlin
val mDelay = delay(800)
// mDelay.continue()
// mDelay.cancel()
```

Is there some function like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `debounce` https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/debounce.html

> Returns a flow that mirrors the original flow, but filters out values that are followed by the newer values within the given timeout. The latest value is always emitted.

Comment: I don't see how I can use `debounce`  in my code

Comment: Create a Flow of `queryTextChanged` events and debounce it. Your current code basically does that but with more manual work. Execute the query from `queryTextSubmit`, and while collecting the flow of `queryTextChanged` check that the query you are about to make is not the same as the last one already issued.

Comment: @Bouh Try this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/63482127/11191424