# How to avoid multiple api calls for single button click in android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

On Button click ,using retrofit Making API call then logging success response. In Logs i observed api is calling multiple times [image][same problem i think](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2367) here is my code to build api.

```
 fun <Api> buildApi(api: Class<Api>, authToken: String? = null): Api {
    return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Global.BASE_URL)
        .client(OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                chain.proceed(
                    chain.request().newBuilder()
                        .also {
                            it.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $authToken")
                        }.build()
                )

            }
            .also { client ->
                val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
                client.addInterceptor(logging)
            }.build()
        ).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build().create(api)
}
```

Comment: for example you can disable btn till response getting, any response

Comment: Yes i tried it but didn't work , btn click is happening at once but api is calling multiple times because multiple API instances are created

Comment: Disabling the button isn't enough to prevent multiple rapid taps of the button from getting through, so you also need to debounce it. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60193549/506796)

Comment: Button click isn't the problem , Because onClick is happening at once. Problem is api is calling multiple times because retrofit instance is created multiple time

Comment: @Tenfour04 Tried debounce but no luck, Issue is different. As retrofit instance is created multiple time need to restrict to single instance https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2367. But i didn't get how to implement the same here

Comment: try moving the last line where you observe `materialSearchResult` outside of your onClickListener lambda. it should not be inside there.