# Is it possible to debounce onClick callback right in a listener?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a listener for zooming in and out mapview:

```
class ZoomMapListener(
    mapView: MapView,
    private val zoom: Zoom,
) : View.OnClickListener {

    private val localMapView = WeakReference(mapView)
    private var clickCount = 0

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        clickCount++
    }

    fun moveCamera() {
        val mapView = localMapView.get()

        mapView?.let {
            var cameraPosition = it.map.cameraPosition

            val zoom = if (zoom == IN) {
                cameraPosition.zoom + (1.0f * clickCount)
            } else {
                cameraPosition.zoom - (1.0f * clickCount)
            }

            cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
                cameraPosition.target,
                zoom,
                cameraPosition.azimuth,
                cameraPosition.tilt,
            )

            clickCount = 0

            it.map.move(cameraPosition, Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0.5f), null)
        }
    }
}

enum class Zoom {
    IN,
    OUT
}
```

In order if user clicks on button several times I've decided to use debounce operator from another answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/60234167/13236614), so if there are five clicks, for example, camera makes fivefold increase in one operation.

The extension function:

```
@FlowPreview
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun View.setDebouncedListener(
    listener: ZoomMapListener,
    lifecycleCoroutineScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope,
) {
    callbackFlow {
        setOnClickListener {
            listener.onClick(this@setDebouncedListener)
            offer(Unit)
        }
        awaitClose {
            setOnClickListener(null)
        }
    }
        .debounce(500L)
        .onEach { listener.moveCamera() }
        .launchIn(lifecycleCoroutineScope)
}
```

And how I use it in my fragment:

```
zoomInMapButton.setDebouncedListener(ZoomMapListener(mapView, Zoom.IN), lifecycleScope)
```

I think it all looks kinda bad and I'm doubting because of `@FlowPreview` annotation, so is there a way to make it right in the custom listener class at least?

Comment: When you say it "looks kinda bad", do you mean the movement of your camera and responsiveness of your buttons look bad, or do you mean your code doesn't look elegant?

Comment: yes, i'm afraid this code seems to me not that elegant and reliable as it should be :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something with `@FlowPreview` or `@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi` is sort of like using a deprecated function, because it's possible it will stop working as expected or be removed in a future version of the library. They are relatively stable, but you'll need to check them each time you update your core Kotlin libraries.

My coroutine-free answer on that other question is more like `throttleFirst` than `debounce`, because it doesn't delay the first click.

I think you can directly handle debounce in your ZoomListener class by changing only one line of code! Replace `clickCount++` with `if (++clickCount == 1) v.postDelayed(::moveCamera, interval)`.

Disclaimer: I didn't test this.

The strategy here is on the first click to immediately post a delayed call to `moveCamera()`. If any clicks come in during that delay time, they do not post new delayed calls, because their contribution is accounted for in the `clickCount` that `moveCamera()` will use when the delay is over.

I also did some cleanup in `moveCamera()`, but it's functionally the same. In my opinion, `?.let` should not be used for local variables because you can take advantage of smart casting (or early returns) for local variables, so you can keep your code more readable and less nested.

```
class ZoomMapListener(
    mapView: MapView,
    private val zoom: Zoom,
    private val interval: Long
) : View.OnClickListener {

    private val localMapView = WeakReference(mapView)
    private var clickCount = 0

    override fun onClick(v: View) {
        if (++clickCount == 1) v.postDelayed(::moveCamera, interval)
    }

    fun moveCamera() {
        val map = localMapView.get()?.map ?: return
        val multiplier = if (zoom == IN) 1f else -1f
        val newCameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder(map.cameraPosition)
            .zoom(map.cameraPosition.zoom + multiplier * clickCount)
            .build()

        clickCount = 0

        map.move(newCameraPosition, Animation(Animation.Type.SMOOTH, 0.5f), null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...so is there a way to make it right in the custom listener class at least?

If I'm not mistaken, you want to make the debounce in the method of `onClick`, right?

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        // debounce
        clickCount++
    }
```

If that, why not use this reference link [it's in the link you provided]
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60193549/11835023

Comment: I need to count clicks while timeout time is passing(user clicks -> time starts to pass -> after that I can move camera depending on click counts) and this solution doesn't make it work the proper way, idk maybe I've implemented it the wrong way, but don't think so